# Chief factors and local formation

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Every thing below is concerned with finite groups.

My question is about this [paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ78_03%2FS1446788700008624a.pdf&code=bfe417e395eddf83954f7b01a59f9543)

A class of groups is a collection $\mathcal{X}$ of groups with the property that 
if $G \in \mathcal{X}$ and if $H \cong G$, then $H \in \mathcal{X}$.

A class of groups $\mathcal{F}$ is called a formation, provided that the following
conditions are satisfied:

(1) If $G \in \mathcal{F}$, then $G/N \in \mathcal{F}$ for any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$,

(2) If $G/M$ and $G/N$ are both in $\mathcal{F}$, then $G/(M \cap N) \in \mathcal{F}$ for any normal subgroups $M$ and $N$ of $G$.

Now let $\Pi$ be the set of all prime numbers. Then, by a formation function $f$,
we mean a function $f$ define on $\Pi$ such that $f(P)$, possibly empty, is a formation.
A chief factor $H/K$ of a group $G$ is called $f$-central in $G$ if $G/C_{G}(H/K) \in f(p)$ for all primes $p$ dividing $|H/K|$. A formation is a local formation if there exists a formation function $f$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is a local formation defined by $f$ and we write $\mathcal{F}=LF(f)$ and call $f$ a local definition of $\mathcal{F}$.

Among all the possible local definitions for a local formation , there exists
exactly one of them, denoted it by $F$, such that $F$ is integrated (i.e., $F(p) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ for all $p \in \Pi$) and full (i.e., $\mathcal{S}_{p}F(p) = F(p)$ for all $p \in \Pi$) where $\mathcal{S}_{p}$ is the class of $p$-groups.

How did the author used Lemma 2.3 [(see the lemma)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqfAz.png)

in this portion of the proof of Corollary 3.2. [(see the portion)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7CEr.png)?

My question is exactly in the line that is underlined with blue. How did the authors conclude that $G/C_{G}(K_{1}/K_{2}) \in F_{1}(q)$?

I know that one possible local definition for the class of $p$-nilpotent groups, denoted by $\mathcal {N}_{p}$, is the following:
We define the formation function as follows:
$f(p)=(1)$ and $f(q)=\mathcal {G}$ for $q \neq p$, Where $(1)$ is the class that contains only the trivial group $\{1\}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is the class of all finite groups.

According to the above local definition of $p$-nilpotent groups
$G/C_{G}(K_{1}/K_{2}) \in f(q)$ clearly as $f(q)= \mathcal{G}$ the class of all finite groups. But the problem is that is this local definition is not integrated as $\mathcal{G}$ is not contained in the class of $p$-nilpotent groups $\mathcal {N}_{p}$.

I think that the full and integrated formation function (which is unique) $F_{1}$ for the class of $p$-nilpotent $\mathcal {N}_{p}$ groups is given by 
$F_{1}(p)=\mathcal{S}_{p}$ and $F_{1}(q)=\mathcal {N}_{p}$ for $q \neq p$, Where ${S}_{p}$ is the class of all finite $p$-groups and $\mathcal {N}_{p}$ is the class of all $p$-nilpotent groups. However I do not know how to prove that $G/C_{G}(K_{1}/K_{2})$ is $p$-nilpotent so that $G/C_{G}(K_{1}/K_{2}) \in \mathcal {N}_{p} = F_{1}(q)$.